# Merging two rows using CSS Grid

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

I'm struggling to create the layout I want as it looks like I need .col-3 to merge with .col-1 on desktops, but I don't know how to do it - is it possible?

**Desktop**

[image: Desktop grid layout]

**Mobile**

| .col-1 |

| .col-2 |

| .col-3 |

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="grid-items col-1">
        <p>Slider - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-items col-2">
        <p>Description - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-items col-3">
        <p>Related items - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.grid-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 260px auto 23% 5%;
    column-gap: 3%;
}
.col-1 {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 2;
}
.col-2 {
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 3;
}
.col-3 {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1090px) {
    .grid-wrapper {
        grid-template-columns: 260px auto;
    }
    .col-1, .col-2, .col-3 {
        grid-column-start: 2;
        grid-column-end: 3;
    }
    .col-1 {
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: 2;
    }
    .col-2 {
        grid-row-start: 2;
        grid-row-end: 3;
    }
    .col-3 {
        grid-row-start: 3;
        grid-row-end: 4;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .grid-wrapper {
        grid-template-columns: auto;
    }
    .col-1, .col-2, .col-3 {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this? Surely this must be a common thing for web developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the height of the rows, see snippet below

```css
.grid-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 260px auto 23% 5%;
    grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr; /* added */
    column-gap: 3%;
}
.col-1 {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 2;
}
.col-2 {
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 3;
}
.col-3 {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="grid-items col-1">
        <p>Slider - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-items col-2">
        <p>Description - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-items col-3">
        <p>Related items - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Amazing, so simple but so helpful. Thank you!